# How to fetch Mail-Enable security Groups in SPFx react?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph, react-webpart

I want to show  Mail-Enable security Group Names in select tag.

Can someone please tell how can I get the group names using SPFx react?

Comment: does below solution help you in any way?

Comment: I tried this solution ,but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Are you facing any issue while using it?

Comment: thank you so much for helping me, when I tried this solution , it shows an error 'Page Not Found' . Then I did  it by adding all group names in a list. After that I didn't work on this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Microsoft Graph APIs to get the details of Mail-enabled security groups.

For example:

You can use the query endpoint like below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=mailEnabled eq true and securityEnabled eq true
```

**Documentation**: [Working with groups in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groups-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Also, check this documentation: [Consume the Microsoft Graph in the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial)

This may return mail enabled M365 groups as well. Usually M365 groups have 'Unified' value in `groupType` property. So you can filter results based on this property in your code to exclude M365 groups from results array.

Similar thread (not worked for me): [Query Mail Enabled Security group from Graph API .net SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/910879/query-mail-enabled-security-group-from-graph-api-n)